# Setting boolean with th:checked

Tags: java, checkbox, thymeleaf

I have a model which includes a boolean 'deleted'. I generate a list and each element has this variable within it.

I print it out in a list and I'm trying to set it using a checkbox, so it saves whatever is set.

**Model**

```
public class entry{
private boolean deleted;

public entry(boolean deleted){
this.deleted = deleted;
}

//setters & getters for deleted
}
```

I then have my thymeleaf form read in this list using a wrapper class. Which works fine.

I can get the checkbox to display checked/unchecked depending on the deleted state for each element, but it if I change the checkbox from checked to unchecked...it doesn't then save the variable to that state.

**HTML**

```
<div th:each="entry, stat: *{entryList}">
  <td>
    <label class="switch"> 
      <input name="index" th:type="checkbox" th:checked="*{entryList[__${stat.index}__].deleted}">
      </input> <span class="delete round">
    </span>
    </label>
 </td>
       </div>
```

**TH:Object**

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{submitData}" class="saveForm"
            method="post" th:object="${entryWrapper}">
...
...
</form>
```

**Wrapper Class**

```
public class EntryWrapper {

    @Autowired
    private List<Entry> entryList;

    public EntryWrapper(){

    }

    public EntryWrapper(List<Entry> entryList){
        this.entryList = entryList;
    }

    public List<Entry> getEntryList(){
        return entryList;
    }

    public void add(final Entry entry){
        this.entryList.add(entry);
    }

    public void setEntryList(List<Entry> entryList){
        this.entryList = entryList;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does entryList look like? List<entry>?  Also, what is your th:object?

Comment: have included the wrapper class contents and th:object. the @{submitData} just takes the user to the view of the list without the ability to edit entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `th:checked`, you should use `th:field`

```
<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{entryList[__${stat.index}__].deleted}">
```

`th:field` will generate the name, id and checked attributes, so when you post the form it should populate your model object.

Comment: Thank you :) I had given this a go, but couldn't select the checkboxes at all. However this was an issue with using <label> I believe. It now seems to work!